# Orthonormals, v1,v2.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, orthogonality

Given: $2$ vectors $v1,v2 \ne 0$ and $v1 \ne v2$ and $v1,v2 \in R^n$

Prove: $\{v1\}^\bot = \{v2\}^\bot$ if and only if ${v_1,v_2}$ are linearly dependent.

Well, I do have a solution for this but I didn't understand it well and I'll be really glad if you guys can explain how to prove it. (both ways because of "if and only if")

If needed, I can write the given solution, although I didn't understand it so I prefer to see if you can help me sort out what I didn't understand by giving your solution with some explanation if possible.

Comment: Do you mean by $\{v_1\}^\bot$ the subspace perpendicular to $v_1$? If so, then the statement is not true.

Comment: @NickyHekster It is true because $v_1$ and $v_2$ are assumed to be nonzero; thus they are linearly dependent iff $v_1=\lambda v_2$ with $\lambda\ne0$.

Comment: I must be missing something - take $v_1=(1,0,0)$ and $v_2=(0,1,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $\{v_1\}^\bot$ and $\{v_2\}^\bot$ are two perpendicular planes, so not equal ...

Comment: @NickyHekster These $v_1$ and $v_2$ are NOT linearly dependent.

Comment: Ah, that explains it, I read *in*dependent!Thanks Vladimir.

Comment: Any ideas how to prove that guys?

Answer (score 2):

If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent and are both nonzero, then it is easy to see that $v_1=\lambda v_2$ with $\lambda\ne0$. Thus, all vectors orthogonal to $v_2$ will be orthogonal to $v_1$ and vice versa. If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, then the vector $\xi=v_1-\frac{(v_1,v_2)}{||v_2||^2}v_2$ is nonzero and orthogonal to $v_2$ but not to $v_1$.
Indeed, $(\xi,v_2)=0$ by straightforward computation. $(\xi,v_1)=||v_1||^2-\frac{(v_1,v_2)^2}{||v_2||^2}$. If $(\xi,v_1)=0$, then $||v_1||^2||v_2||^2=(v_1,v_2)^2$ and hence
$$
||v_1-\lambda v_2||^2=||v_1^2||+\lambda^2||v_2||^2-2\lambda(v_1,v_2)
$$
is zero for $\lambda=(v_1,v_2)/||v_2||^2$; i.e., $v_1=\lambda v_2$, a contradiction. QED

Comment: Vladimir, well done, you were quicker than me, I withdrew my answer ... :-)) +1 from me.

Comment: @NickyHekster Have not intended to win the race; sorry;)

Comment: No, no, no problem, there is no race (maybe gamification ...), you gave a perfect answer to the question!!!

Comment: Well, I'm I don't understand the material enough to understand your solution, I'm sorry. I'll go study again the material and hope I'll get it figured out. Thanks!

Comment: @Vladimir Just wrote an answer, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

> If $\{v_2,v_1\}$ are linearly dependent then: $v_2 = \Lambda v_1$
>
> $ v \in \{v_1\}^\bot \iff v * v_1 =0 \iff v * \Lambda v_1 = 0 \iff v * v_2 = 0 \iff v \in \{v_2\}^\bot$
>
> Which means $ \{v_1\}^\bot = \{v_2\}^\bot $.

Now, the other way:

> If $ \{v_1\}^\bot = \{v_2\}^\bot $ then,
>
> We know that every sub-set of A holds $(A^\bot)^\bot = Sp(A)$
>
> So we can say that $ \{v_1\} = \{v_2\} $ Thus,
>
> We can say that $v_1 = Sp(v_1)$ and $v_2 = Sp(v_2)$ $\rightarrow$ $Sp(v_1) = Sp(v_2)$ Thus,
>
> $\{v1,v2\}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: @Vladimir what do you think? I don't know if my explanation in the second part was good.

Comment: No, it makes little sense to me, for I do not understand for example what you mean by $Sp(v_1)=v_1$. (This is only one example.) If you amend all these small errors, the argument will only be good if you already know that $(A^\perp)^\perp=\operatorname{span}A$

Comment: If $ \{v_1\}^\bot = \{v_2\}^\bot $ , does it mean that $ \{v_1\} = \{v_2\} $ ? Which means that I can also write it as $Sp(v_1) = Sp(v_2)$ which I can say that $\{v1,v2\}$ are linearly dependent?

Comment: Maybe I just do not understand you notation well. What is the difference between {v} and Sp(v)?

Comment: I guess not difference.

Comment: The right solution depends on what has been proved earlier. If you already know that $(A^\perp)^\perp=\{A\}$, then your problem is trivial. If not, you can use my solution for example (which is anyway a special case of a proof of the fact that $(A^\perp)^\perp=Sp(A)$.

Comment: Got it now, $\{v_1^\bot \}^\bot = Sp(v_1) = Sp(v_2) = \{v_2^\bot \}^\bot$ Thus,$\rightarrow$ $\{v_1,v_2\}$ are linearly dependent.